# Not able to use and stop a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16455953/2277645) from my last question. But now I am unable to use and stop the Thread just after one minute after doing my things. I actually want to close/stop the thread after one minute after doing my things. So, I'm badly confused: how can I do this using:

```
public class Frame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable{
    public Frame2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void run(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime ) < 1000) {        
            System.out.print("DOING MY THINGS");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it is not working at all and when I close the frame containing this Thread the line of code

```
    System.out.print("DOING MY THINGS");
```

works in an infinite loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595490/stop-a-thread-after-period-of-time

Comment: What do initComponents do? It's not a part of JFrame api.

Comment: Have you ever use NetBeans? lols

Comment: No I did not. Well, in that case, it's part of some NetBeans API. Anyway, just start the Thread manually with `new Thread(this).start()`.

Answer (score 3):

> when I close the frame containing this Thread

Frame does not contain threads. Frame can have a reference to it. But the thread itself will run until it's execution is complete (`run` method ends) and not a second less.

You can not just "stop" the Thread. It must **always** complete it's execution (again, `run` method to end).

The code you wrote should be working pretty well and stop writing stuff in 60 seconds. If you want it to terminate on you closing the frame, you should add some variable to check against and write `true` to it when you want the thread to terminate.

Example:

```
private volatile boolean terminated = false;

public void run(){
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  while (!terminated && System.currentTimeMillis() < startTime + 60000) {
    System.out.print("DOING MY THINGS");
    // here I want to do my things done in just one minute
    // and after that I want to stop the thread at will!
  }
}

public void stop() {
  terminated = true;
}
```

Comment: actually the system.out command is not working when I start the thread and when I just click the JFrame close button the Thread stops itself executing the system.out.print command in an infinite loop

Comment: Then we need to see more of your code, the error is somewhere else. The thread looks pretty ok by itself.